# PHP Oracle query select statement inside loop slow

Tags: php, oracle

I have this php function to check and insert data from text file to database.

```
//Get All Model
$qModel = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT MODELID, MODEL_NAME FROM MEP_TBL_MODEL WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND LOCATION = 'PCBA' ORDER BY MODELID ASC");
oci_execute($qModel);
while($dModel = oci_fetch_array($qModel))
{
    //Configuration
    $qDtl = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_MODEL_CONFIGURATION WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "'");
    oci_execute($qDtl);
    while($dDtl = oci_fetch_array($qDtl))
    {
        $modelIDAccept[] = $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'];
        $dateCode = date($dDtl['DATE_CODE']);
        $readRowAfter = date($dDtl['READ_ROW_AFTER']);
        $createFromFormat = $dDtl['CREATE_FROM_FORMAT'];
        $ipAddress = $dDtl['IP_ADDRESS'];
        $status = $dDtl['STATUS'];

        if($dDtl['SOURCE'] != "")
        {
            $source = "\\".$dDtl['SOURCE'];
        }
        else
        {
            $source = "";
        }

        if(empty($ipAddress))
        {
            $fileAccept = file_get_contents("\\\\192.168.184.13\\Reports\\".$dModel['MODEL_NAME'].$source."\\Accept\\Accept_".$dDtl['MODEL_CODE']."_".$dateCode."_".$dDtl['TS_CODE'].".txt");

            $linesAccept = explode("\n",$fileAccept);
            $rowsintimespanAccept = 0;

            for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesAccept); $i++)
            {
                $dateobjAccept = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesAccept[$i]);

                if($dateobjAccept < $toDateTime && $dateobjAccept > $fromDateTime)
                {
                    $rowsintimespanAccept++;

                    $logDate = $dateobjAccept->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    //I put select query and insert here but it so slow.
                    $qChk = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "' AND RUNNING_DATE = TO_DATE('$logDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND TS_CODE = '" . $dDtl['TS_CODE'] . "' AND SHIFT = 'Morning' AND QUANTITY_STATUS = 'OK' AND CONFIGURATIONID_FK = '" . $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'] . "'");
                    oci_execute($qChk);
                    if(oci_fetch($qChk) > 0)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $qInsert = oci_parse($c1, "INSERT INTO MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS(MODELID_FK, RUNNING_DATE, QUANTITY_STATUS, TS_CODE, SHIFT, CONFIGURATIONID_FK) VALUES('" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "', TO_DATE('$logDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 'OK', '" . $dDtl['TS_CODE'] . "', 'Morning', '" . $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'] . "')");
                        oci_execute($qInsert);
                    }
                }
            }

            $totalAccept[] = $rowsintimespanAccept;
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the code, I got very slow loading the page and sometimes it show me time out execution.

My question, is there any way to make the query fast maybe inside or outside the loop? I knew it slow because when I remove the select and insert query, the load page is only 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Mind the SQL injection pretty sure ocl API supports prepared statements otherwise you need to use PDO instead.. It's seams you are ueed it wrong here SQL injections are still possible.

Comment: Basically you are doing a join of 3 tables and insert of the result in an other table. So try to formulate it as a pure SQL: `insert into ... select join of the tree tables`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber how can I do that? Kindly give me an example.

Comment: Running SELECT queries inside a loop is an anti-pattern - use a join outside the loop. Splicing parameters into a statement then parsing the statement before executing it is an anti-pattern. Use parameter binding and parse the statement outside the loop.

Comment: Splicing literal values into into an SQL statement without escaping them is also an anti-pttern commonly described as "SQL Injection", too.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your code correctly, what you're after is a single MERGE statement that you can run on the database. I don't know PHP, so I can't give you how it should be called, but I can give you the SQL statement to run:

```
MERGE INTO mep_tbl_output_details tgt
  USING (SELECT mtm.modelid,
                mtm.model_name,
                mtmc.configurationid,
                mtmc.date_code,
                mtmc.read_row_after,
                mtmc.create_from_format,
                mtmc.ip_address,
                mtmc.status,
                mtmc.ts_code
         FROM   mep_tbl_model mtm
                INNER JOIN mep_tbl_model_configuration mtmc ON mtm.modelid = mtmc.modelid_fk
         WHERE  mtm.active = 'Y'
         AND    mtm.location = 'PCBA') src
    ON (tgt.modelid_fk = src.modelid
        AND tgt.ts_code = src.ts_code
        AND tgt.configurationid_fk = src.configurationid
        AND tgt.runningdate = :log_date
        AND tgt.shift = 'Morning'
        AND tgt.quantity_status = 'OK')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.modelid_fk, tgt.running_date, tgt.quantity_status, tgt.ts_code, tgt.shift, tgt.configuration_fk)
  VALUES (src.modelid, :log_date, 'OK', src.ts_code, 'Morning', src.configurationid);
```

This does the join you were reinventing with your loops, links it back to the table you're trying to insert into, and only inserts a row if it doesn't already exist in the table.

You would need to write the PHP code to execute this, having passed the log_date in as a bind variable.

By binding the variable, you allow the database to skip the hard parse (i.e. finding out the best way to execute the query), which saves time.

By not fetching data and manually looping round before selecting more data and working out if you need to do the insert, you skip a whole lot of context switching and pulling/pushing data across the network. Let the database do the heavy lifting; it's what it's designed to do!

Answer (score 0):

Your code's performance will be enhanced by some changes I made.In this modification, I have rewritten the code to comply with the OCI standard

```
<?php
     // Get all model IDs and names
    $qModel = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT MODELID, MODEL_NAME FROM MEP_TBL_MODEL WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND LOCATION = 'PCBA' ORDER BY MODELID ASC");
    oci_execute($qModel);
    
    // Loop through each model
    while ($dModel = oci_fetch_array($qModel)) {
        // Get all configurations for this model
        $qDtl = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_MODEL_CONFIGURATION WHERE MODELID_FK = :modelid");
        oci_bind_by_name($qDtl, ":modelid", $dModel['MODELID']);
        oci_execute($qDtl);
    
        // Loop through each configuration for this model
        while ($dDtl = oci_fetch_array($qDtl)) {
            // Get configuration details
            $modelIDAccept[] = $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID'];
            $dateCode = $dDtl['DATE_CODE'];
            $readRowAfter = $dDtl['READ_ROW_AFTER'];
            $createFromFormat = $dDtl['CREATE_FROM_FORMAT'];
            $ipAddress = $dDtl['IP_ADDRESS'];
            $status = $dDtl['STATUS'];
            $source = $dDtl['SOURCE'] ?: "";
    
            // Check if IP address is empty
            if (empty($ipAddress)) {
                // Get file contents
                $filePath = "\\\\192.168.184.13\\Reports\\" . $dModel['MODEL_NAME'] . $source . "\\Accept\\Accept_" . $dDtl['MODEL_CODE'] . "_" . $dateCode . "_" . $dDtl['TS_CODE'] . ".txt";
                $fileAccept = file_get_contents($filePath);
    
                // Loop through each line of the file
                $linesAccept = explode("\n", $fileAccept);
                $rowsintimespanAccept = 0;
                foreach ($linesAccept as $line) {
                    // Parse the date from the line according to the specified format
                    $dateobjAccept = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $line);
    
                    // Check if the date is within the specified range
                    if ($dateobjAccept >= $fromDateTime && $dateobjAccept <= $toDateTime) {
                        $rowsintimespanAccept++;
    
                        // Insert output details into database
                        $logDate = $dateobjAccept->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $qChk = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS WHERE MODELID_FK = :modelid AND RUNNING_DATE = TO_DATE(:logdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND TS_CODE = :tscode AND SHIFT = 'Morning' AND QUANTITY_STATUS = 'OK' AND CONFIGURATIONID_FK = :configid");
                        oci_bind_by_name($qChk, ":modelid", $dModel['MODELID']);
                        oci_bind_by_name($qChk, ":logdate", $logDate);
                        oci_bind_by_name($qChk, ":tscode", $dDtl['TS_CODE']);
                        oci_bind_by_name($qChk, ":configid", $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID']);
                        oci_execute($qChk);
                        if (!oci_fetch($qChk)) {
                            $qInsert = oci_parse($c1, "INSERT INTO MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS(MODELID_FK, RUNNING_DATE, QUANTITY_STATUS, TS_CODE, SHIFT, CONFIGURATIONID_FK) VALUES(:modelid, TO_DATE(:logdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 'OK', :tscode, 'Morning', :configid)");
                            oci_bind_by_name($qInsert, ":modelid", $dModel['MODELID']);
                            oci_bind_by_name($qInsert, ":logdate", $logDate);
                            oci_bind_by_name($qInsert, ":tscode", $dDtl['TS_CODE']);
                            oci_bind_by_name($qInsert, ":configid", $dDtl['CONFIGURATIONID']);
                            oci_execute($qInsert);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                $totalAccept[] = $rowsintimespanAccept;
            }
        }
    } 
        
        ?>
```